# AngularJS its sending file in a body and not in file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

i have an angularjs service to send a file to a NodeJS server.

This is the code:

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    var UploadService = function (API_URL, $http) {
        var uploadFile = function (file, uploadUrl) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            return $http.post(API_URL + uploadUrl,fd,{
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            });

        };
        return {
            uploadFile: uploadFile
        };
    };
    return UploadService;
});
```

My problem its the file its sending in the body and not in the file, then in my nodejs when i parse with a middleware, because the request.file its undefined dont parse any file.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Why won't you use a library for that?

Comment: I dont know anyone library..i create the file in runtime with jspdf library, all the librarys provided a directive to upload file from computer..